# Need help with Javascript Regular Expressions - Splitting text

Tags: javascript, regex, string, split

I have a string that represents a list of tags separated by space. It may look like this:

```
Australia 2010 David November Family
```

If a tag contains at least one space, it must be quoted. So the string can be:

```
"Best Friends" "My Pictures" Wow "Very Nice Photo" University
```

Quotes are also allowed for single words. For example:

```
"Good One" Fantastic "February" "My Family" "Friends"
```

The question is:
How would you get an array of tags from the string ?
For example, from the third string I would like to get the following array:

```
arr[0] = "Good One"
arr[1] = "Fantastic"
arr[2] = "February"
arr[3] = "My Family"
arr[4] = "Friends"
```

If the string is not in the right format, I would like to know about it (for example: to get empty array as a result).

Comment: If you want to create a line break , just put two spaces at the end of the line. See also:http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help or the `How to format` box when you create a new question.

Comment: What would be *not* a right format?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a regular expression like `/"[^"]+"|\w+/` to match the tags.
To get an array containing all the matches without quotation marks, you can use something like

```
var re = /"[^"]+"|\w+/g;
var result = [];
var match;
while(match = re.exec(input))
    result.push(match[0].replace(/"/g, ""));
```

If you don't have to remove the quotation marks, you can just use

```
var result = input.match(re);
```

Comment: `/"[^"]+"|\S+/g` would add support for any character in unquoted strings